# I need to convert some coordinate to pixel x,y

Tags: php, svg, canvas, autocad

The problem is I don't know what this coordinate 
called "3562.1< s36 d 26 ' n"

I don't know if  it's called bearing or UTM coordinate
To help. the coordinate was used to plot a lot on AutoCAD or ark gis

< angle

```
' minute
S south
D degree
N north
```

Comment: Welcome to stack oveflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert polar to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: apokryfos I want this ex "3562.1<s36d34'n" to convert to pixel

Comment: if You follow @AlexandreCartapanis suggestion and ask the question as should be, I suppose I have a solution for You.